# How to tell which magazines I've found

Tags: fallout-4

I've found a few magazines in the game but I've since sold them and forgotten which ones they were.  Is there any way to find out which ones I've found so far?

Comment: According to the wiki, each different copy of each magazine has an effect, so you probably still want to find them all.

Comment: It depends which magazine. For magazines like total hack and astoundingly awesome tales, yes. For most magazines though, like covert operations and guns and bullets, no.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no way to know exactly which magazine you've found, but there's a way to have an idea of the type you've found to help you narrow the possibilities.

Most magazines* in FO4 will add a rank of a particular perk.  For example, Grognak the Barbarian will add a rank of the Barbarian perk, giving you 5% more critical damage with melee/unarmed attacks.

If your Barbarian perk is at rank 3 that means you've found 3 of them.

Also, there is a handy Fallout 4 map you can use to keep track of which ones you've found so far.

Its located at http://fallout4map.com/

*Some magazines, like Picket Fences and Astonishingly Awesome gives other benefits that are harder to track.

Comment: Each edition of a comic/magazine is different. You can tell by looking at the cover of each one. As for the perks from Astoundingly Awesome, those are listed in the pip-boy. I think they all have the same name, but the effect is different for each.

Answer (score 10):

[This guide](http://www.ign.com/wikis/fallout-4/Books_and_Magazines) lists them all by subtitles, so you can differentiate between each edition.

**Astoundingly Awesome Tales**

- *A Gorilla Ate My Patrol Car*: Old north church - Railroad HQ
- *Attack of the Fishmen*: Skylanes Flight 1981
- *Attack of the Metal Men*: Dunwich Borers
- *Curse of the burned*: Crater of Atom
- *Giant Insects Invade*: Sentinel Site
- *Have Dog, Will Travel*: The Institute
- *Invasion of the Zetans*: Hubris Comics
- *My Brain and I*: Boston Mayoral Shelter
- *Rise of the Mutants*: Trinity Plaza
- *Rise of the Radiated*: East Boston Preparatory School
- *Sinister Seafood Strikes*: Outpost Zimonja
- *The Mad Russian's Revenge*: Pickman Gallery
- *The Man Who Could Stop Time*: Park Street Station - Vault 114
- *The Starlet Sniper*: Coast Guard Pier

**Grognak the Barbarian**

- *Blood on the Harp*: Wicked Shipping Fleet Lockup
- *Cometh the Trickster*: Andrew Street Station
- *Demon Slaves, Demon Sands*: Vault 75
- *Demon Slaves, Demon Sands* - Alternate Issue: Vault 81
- *Enter Maula: War Maiden of Mars*: Boston Common
- *Fatherless Cur*: Mass Pike Exchange
- *In the Bosom of the Corsair Queen*: Corvega Assembly Plant
- *In the Lair of the Virgin Eaters*: Hyde Park
- *Jungle of the Bat Babies*: Sanctuary
- *Lost in the Snows of Lust*: Back Street Apparel
- *What Sorcery is This?*: Museum of Witchcraft

**Guns and Bullets**

- *Bear Proofing Your Campsite*: Cambridge Police Station
- *Guide to Hunting Commies*: Ticonderoga
- *Lasers and Hunting, Acceptable Overkill*: Fort Hagen
- *Little Guns for Little Ladies*: Fraternal Post 115
- *Plasma, the Weapons of Tomorrow*: The Castle
- *Street Guns of Detroit*: Gunners Plaza
- *Take Aim, Army Style*: S. Boston Military Checkpoint
- *The Future of Hunting?*: BADTFL Regional Office
- *The Moon: A Communist Doomsday Device!?*: Quincy Ruins
- *Void Those Pesky Gun Laws*: Rook Family House

**Hot Rodder**

- *Flame Job*: Robotics Disposal Ground
- *Hot Pink*: Milton General Hospital - West Roxbury Parking Garage
- *Shark Paint Scheme*: Atom Cats Garage

**La Coiffe**

- *Megaton Hair*: Fallon's Department Store
- *The Hornet's Nest*: Bunker Hill - Charleston Laundry

**Live and Love**

- *Advice From Married Men*: Goodneighbor - The Third Rail
- *An Experience to Remember*: Goodneighbor - Hotel Rexford
- *Beware the Man Handler*: Bunker Hill
- *I Married a Robot*: Diamond City Market - Schoolhouse
- *Life Long Best Friends*: Faneuil Hall
- *Nuke the Man*: College Square
- *Talk Yourself Sober*: Revere Beach Station
- *The Secretary Charmer*: Fiddler's Green Trailer Estates
- *Trim the Fat*: WRVR Broadcast Station

**Massachusetts Surgical Journal**

- *Better Living Through Chems*: Cabot House
- *Cryo-Technology: Haven or Tomb*: Greater Mass Blood Clinic
- *ER Nurses Confess All*: Medford Memorial Hospital
- *Find Your Funny Bone*: Boston Public Library
- *Happy Sedation Special*: Sandy Coves Convalescent Home
- *Let's Play Doctor*: Parsons State Insane Asylum
- *Pay Now, Get Better Later*: Greentech Genetics
- *Raised by Robots*: Med-Tek Research
- *Scars are Cool*: Cambridge Polymer Labs

**Picket Fences**

- *Essential Upgrades*: Saugus Ironworks
- *Modern Hearth*: Hardware Town
- *Modern Lawn Care*: Combat Zone
- *The Home of Tomorrow, Today*: Beantown Brewery
- *Welcome Home*: Weston Water Treatment Plant

**Robco Fun**

- *Atomic Command*: Museum of History
- *Grognak and the Ruby Ruins*: Goodneighbor - Memory Den
- *Pipfall*: Fort Hagen - Command Center
- *Red Menace*: Vault 111 (Holotape only)
- *Zeta Invaders*: Diamond City Market - Valentine Detective Agency

**Tales of a Junktown Jerky Vendor**

- *Benefits of Child Labor*: Longneck Lukowski's Cannery
- *Capitalism and You*: Four Leaf Fishpacking Plant
- *How to Run a Successful Vendor Stand*: Big John's Salvage
- *Suit Up and Succeed*: Wreck of the FMS Northern Star
- *Take Your Business on the Road*: Mystic Pines
- *The Art of Haggling*: Super Duper Mart
- *The Joy of Wealth*: Gwinett Brewery
- *Why I Sold My Mother*: Walden Pond

**Tesla Science**

- *Blast Off to Adventure!*: Mahkra Fishpacking
- *Future of Warfare?*: Reeb Marina
- *Geckos and Gamma Radiation*: University Point
- *Giant Super Weapons*: Mass Fusion Building
- *Rocket Science for Toddlers*: Rocky Cave - Virgil's Laboratory
- *U.S. Army Goes to Space*: HalluciGen Inc.
- *What is Plasma Anyway?*: General Atomics Factory
- *Will Robots Rule the World?*: Arcjet Systems
- *10 Number 1 Hits*: Poseidon Energy

**Taboo Tattoos**

- *Bad Luck Horseshoe*: Vault 81
- *Eagle's Nest*: Thicket Excavations
- *Lucky Clover*: Mass Pike Tunnel West/East
- *Nautical Anchor*: Concord - Civic Access
- *Skulls are Hip*: Irish Pride Industries Shipyard

**Total Hack**

- *Control Robots*: Waltz Consumer Electronics
- *Control Spotlights*: The Shamrock Taphouse
- *Control Turrets*: Wildwood Cemetery

**Tumblers Today**

- *Bobby Picks - More Effective Than Lockpicks?*: Easy City Downs
- *Confessions of a Housebreaker*: Fens Street Sewers
- *Locksmith Certification Special*: Malden Center
- *Mysteries of the Master Key Exposed!*: Poseidon Energy Turbines #18-F
- *Open Any Lock in 5 Seconds Flat*: West Roxbury Station

**U.S. Covert Operations Manual**

- *Bushes, Boxes, and Beehives Camouflage Special*: Libertalia
- *Facepaint Fundamentals*: Federal Ration Stockpile
- *Getting the Drop on Communists*: National Guard Training Yard
- *Look Better in Black*: Revere Satellite Array
- *Not the Soldiers You're Looking For*: Abandoned Shack
- *Squeaky Floorboard, Sudden Death*: Fort Hagen - Command Center
- *Tiptoe Through the Tulips*: USAF Satellite Station Olivia
- *Urban Camoflage*: U.S.S. Constitution
- *Whistling in the Dark*: Lexington - The Switchboard
- *Who Goes There?*: Fort Strong

**Unstoppables**

- *Commie-Kazi vs Manta Man*: Westing Estate
- *Dr. Brainwash and His Army of De-Capitalists*: Shaw High School
- *Trapped in the Dimension of the Sterror-dactyls*: Suffolk County Charter School
- *Visit the Ux-Ron Galaxy*: Hubris Comics
- *Who Can Stop the Unstoppable Grog-na-rok?*: D.B. Technical High School

**Wasteland Survival Guide**

- *Commonwealth Coupon Spectacular*: Nahant Oceanological Society
- *Farming the Wastes*: Wreck of the USS Riptide
- *Guide to Diamond City* - Gorski Cabin
- *Hunting in the Wastes*: Sunshine Tidings Co-op
- *Insect Repellent Special*: Crater House
- *Self-Defense Secrets*: Ranger Cabin
- *The Bright Side of Radiation*: Egret Tours Marina
- *The Scrapyard Home Decoration Group*: Lynn Woods
- *Water Aerobics for Ghouls*: Old Gullet Sinkhole

Comment: There is a "display rack" or something of that sort you can build in your settlements that allow you to display these (if you haven't sold them). (Vanilla, that is, you don't need any add-ons.)

That's how I'm keeping track of mine.

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible to tell which magazines you have picked up, however, you will need to hold on to them to do so efficiently.

For the purpose of better housekeeping, I build magazine racks in my house in Sanctuary, and place all magazines I find on them.

Not only an I visibly see all the magazines I have collected, but it makes it much easier to scroll through a list of them, given they are all in the one place.

In the exact context of OPs problem, this will not help, as it requires you to hold on to the magazines and is impracticable in hindsight. However, given the unique nature of the magazines found in game, this can be a practical way to keep record of future magazines.